# Making overflow resize to fit inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've encountered an interesting problem. I have a `div` that is a container around a menu.

If i set `overflow : hidden` on the menu, the the parts of the menu that overflow are hidden.

Instead of hiding them, I'd like to simply resize the 'group-list' menu flyout so that it'll stay inside my menu.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uW9nG/

In the fiddle, you'll see that if you mouseOver **A**, it flys out over the blue container. If you Toggle the overflow, the overflow will be hidden.

How can I make the overflow simply resize the group-list so that it fits in the container?

(I've been working on this math all morning, and can't quite get it..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `groupList` is currently being given a `margin-top`, but it would be simpler to make it `position:absolute` and then pull it up -50px (to match the 50px you pushed the `<ul id='test-two'>` down. [See fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jayjx/2/)

```
groupList.css({
    'top': '-50px',
    'position': 'absolute'
});
```

If your `#test-two` wasn't positioned, you could just give `groupList` 0px for the `top`.

Answer (score 1):

I forked your fiddle and came up with a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/jayjx/1/).  Just find the top positions of the container and the flyout, then find the difference and relatively position the flyout with that value.  I also had to change the height of the list items to be hard coded at 20px otherwise the list item would change width.

```
var groupListTop = groupList.offset().top;
var containerTop = $('#container').offset().top;
if(groupListTop < containerTop) {
    var diff = containerTop - groupListTop;
    groupList.css({
        position: 'relative',
        top: diff
    })
}
```